# Psake ignores properties and parameters

Tags: build, continuous-integration, build-process, psake

Using **psake 4.5.0** I've tried to run my `default.ps1` file many different ways, passing both `-properties` and `-parameters`, but those values are just ignored **in the root-scope** of the `.ps1`-script.

**Execute relative (*with psake in a subfolder*)**:

```
.\psake-4.5.0\psake.ps1 .\default.ps1 BuildSolution -properties @{"a"="a";"b"="b";"c"="c";"d"="d"} -parameters @{"w"="w";"x"="x";"y"="y";"z"="z"}
```

**Execute with imported module**:

```
Import-Module .\psake-4.5.0\psake.psm1

Invoke-Psake .\default.ps1 BuildSolution -properties @{"a"="a";"b"="b";"c"="c";"d"="d"} -parameters @{"w"="w";"x"="x";"y"="y";"z"="z"}
```

**Execute through installed Chocolatey-package**:

```
psake .\default.ps1 BuildSolution -properties "@{'a'='a';'b'='b';'c'='c';'d'='d'}" -parameters "@{'w'='w';'x'='x';'y'='y';'z'='z'}"
```

**Execute through `cmd.exe`**:

```
psake-4.5.0\psake.cmd default.ps1 BuildSolution -properties "@{'a'='a';'b'='b';'c'='c';'d'='d'}" -parameters "@{'w'='w';'x'='x';'y'='y';'z'='z'}"
```

Right now, the `default.ps1` is simply just debugging all these values:

```
// Since "properties" doesn't get populated, I also try "Param"
Param(
    $w = $w, // Trying to populate from passed param
    $x = $null, // Trying to default to null-value
    $y // Trying another syntax, hoping for population
    // "$z" left out, hoping for population
)

properties {
    $a = $a
    $b = $null
    $c
}

Write-Host "a: $a"
Write-Host "b: $b"
Write-Host "c: $c"
Write-Host "d: $d"
Write-Host "w: $w"
Write-Host "x: $x"
Write-Host "y: $y"
Write-Host "z: $z"

Task BuildSolution -Depends Clean {
    Write-Host "Running BuildSolution"
}

Task Clean {
    Write-Host "Running Clean"
}
```

The output is in all cases:

```
a: 
b: 
c: 
d: 
w: 
x: 
y: 
z:
```

What is the proper syntax to pass `properties` and/or `parameters` to psake?

Comment: does this help at all? https://github.com/psake/psake/tree/master/examples/passingParametersString

Comment: @almog.ori Not really, it's a very theoretical example, while mine is very concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look into this too long but it seems as long as you declare the $variable in properties  { ... here ... }
or in Param (... here ... ) so psake can populate them, they come though okay. You missed $z.  Unless im missing something fundamental about why your using parameters and properties together?

default.ps1

```
properties {
        $a = $null,
        $b = $null,
        $c = $null,
        $w = $null,
        $x = $null,
        $y = $null,
        $z = $null
    }

Task default -Depends BuildSolution 

Task BuildSolution -Depends Clean {
    Write-Host "Running BuildSolution"
    echo "x -> $x"
    echo "y -> $y"
    echo "z -> $z"
}

Task Clean {
    Write-Host "Running Clean"
    echo "a -> $a"
    echo "b -> $b"
    echo "c -> $c"
}
```

invoke code sample (psake installed via chocolatey to c:)

```
Import-Module C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\psake\tools\psake.psm1

Invoke-Psake .\default.ps1  BuildSolution -properties @{'a'="a";"b"="b";"c"="c";'x'="x";'y'="y";'z'="z"}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the `Properties` function Line 256 in psake.psm1, notice it takes a scriptblock args and adds it to properties array on the context stack found on $psake, still script blocks here

```
function Properties {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=1)][scriptblock]$properties
    )
    $psake.context.Peek().properties += $properties
}
```

Line 372 of `Invoke-psake` function in psake.psm1 Loads your default.ps1 build script to scope ( at this point you see your `write-host` calls but no variables loaded )

```
. $psake.build_script_file.FullName
```

Line 394 and Line 397 Loads the script blocks from parameters and properties to the scope.

```
 foreach ($key in $parameters.keys) {
            if (test-path "variable:\$key") {
                set-item -path "variable:\$key" -value $parameters.$key -WhatIf:$false -Confirm:$false | out-null
            } else {
                new-item -path "variable:\$key" -value $parameters.$key -WhatIf:$false -Confirm:$false | out-null
            }
        }
```

...

```
foreach ($key in $properties.keys) {
            if (test-path "variable:\$key") {
                set-item -path "variable:\$key" -value $properties.$key -WhatIf:$false -Confirm:$false | out-null
            }
        }
```

Line 420 and 423 calls `invoke-Task` (Line 198) which in turn uses the variables defined above, also there is an assert that the variables are not null in this function.

I don't think the expected use case involved loading these variables into root scope, when the script is first . sourced into scope it spits out the `write-host` calls then, design probably intended you to declare Task method first so the scope can pass the variables into it and it should be noted.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit from your follow-up questions. All your examples has the properties inside Tasks. My problem is that nothing is populated in the root-scope for debugging.

Comment: I'll take a look tonight about root scope issue  but try add $z first to confirm still broken. Also in meantime just a suggestion but why not make a task for your global scope to run before clean?

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work for the root-scope. I can make it work through `Task`-scope, but this question is about highlighting why it doesn't work in the root-scope and why there is nothing in the documentation about it.